# WPF mvvm Light use dataservice with two-way binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am teaching myself MVVM light by building an example which solves a simple problem I get at work.  We have two records of an ID, one is stored as a `long`, one as a `int`.  For large IDs, the `int` field wraps around.  This program shows possible `long` IDs for a given `int`.

I am trying to work out using the `SimpleIoc` DataServices and so this example is MUCH more complicated than it needs to be.

The DataService is a simple class (`CallIDConverter`) that holds the IDs and calculates the other value and, if given an `int`, other possible `long` values.

When the user types in a new value, the class is being updated and so `RaisePropertyChanged()` is being called, but the view is not being updated.  Is this due to how I am using the `DataService`? Or am I simply missing a `RaisePropertyChanged()` somewhere?.

ViewModelLocator.cs:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, Design.DesignDataService>();
        }
        else
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, CallIdDataService>();
        }
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
    }
    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get { ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>(); } 
    }
}
```

CallIdDataService.cs:

```
public class CallIdDataService : IDataService
{
    public void GetData(Action<CallIdConverter, Exception> callback)
    {
        var item = new CallIdConverter();
        callback(item, null);
    }
}
```

CallIDConverter.cs

```
public class CallIdConverter : ObservableObject
{
    private static long _totalNumberOfInts = Convert.ToInt64(Int32.MaxValue) - Convert.ToInt64(Int32.MinValue) + 1;

    private int _shorewareCallID;
    private long _ccirPrimaryID;
    private List<long> _ccirPossiblePrimaryIDs;

    public int ShorewareCallID { get { return _shorewareCallID; } }
    public long CCIRPrimaryID { get { return _ccirPrimaryID; } }
    public ReadOnlyCollection<long> CCIRPossiblePrimaryIDs { get { return _ccirPossiblePrimaryIDs.AsReadOnly(); } }

    public CallIdConverter()
    {
        this._shorewareCallID = 0;
        this._ccirPrimaryID = 0L;
        this._ccirPossiblePrimaryIDs = new List<long>();
    }

    public void SetShorewareCallID(int callID)
    {
        this._shorewareCallID = callID;
        this._ccirPrimaryID = callID > 0L ? (long)callID : (long)callID + _totalNumberOfInts;
        this._ccirPossiblePrimaryIDs.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            _ccirPossiblePrimaryIDs.Add((long)callID + (i * _totalNumberOfInts));
        }
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => ShorewareCallID);
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => CCIRPrimaryID);
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => CCIRPossiblePrimaryIDs);
    }

    public void SetCCIRPrimaryID(long primaryID)
    {
        this._shorewareCallID = (int)primaryID;
        this._ccirPrimaryID = primaryID;
        this._ccirPossiblePrimaryIDs.Clear();
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => ShorewareCallID);
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => CCIRPrimaryID);
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => CCIRPossiblePrimaryIDs);
    }
}
```

MainViewModel.cs:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IDataService _dataService;
    private CallIdConverter Data { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService)
    {
        _dataService = dataService;
        _dataService.GetData(
            (item, error) =>
            {
                if (error != null)
                {
                    // Report error here
                    return;
                }
                this.Data = item;
            });
    }
    public int ShorewareCallID
    {
        get { return Data.ShorewareCallID; }
        set
        {
            if (Data.ShorewareCallID == value) { return; }
            Data.SetShorewareCallID(value);
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Data);
        }
    }
    public long CCIRPrimaryID
    {
        get { return Data.CCIRPrimaryID; }
        set
        {
            if (Data.CCIRPrimaryID == value) { return; }
            Data.SetCCIRPrimaryID(value);
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Data);
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<long> CCIRPossiblePrimaryIDs
    {
        get { return new ObservableCollection<long>(Data.CCIRPossiblePrimaryIDs); }
    }
}
```

After fiddling, I have discovered that it works if I replace

```
RaisePropertyChanged(() => Data);
```

with

```
RaisePropertyChanged(() => ShorewareCallID);
RaisePropertyChanged(() => CCIRPrimaryID);
RaisePropertyChanged(() => CCIRPossiblePrimaryIDs);
```

This means that `CallIDConverter` doesn't need to inherit from `ObservableObject`.  The problem with this is that the ViewModel needs to know everything that is affected when a method is called on a model class.  This seems to me to not be a good idea.

Comment: Nothing watches `Data` therefore, raising that it has changed simply does nothing.

Comment: Even though I am watching `Data.CCIRPrimaryID`?  If `Data` changes, surely it should check whether a property of `Data` has changed

Comment: That's correct, because the binding (which isn't posted) is likely `{Binding CCIRPrimaryID}`, which has no knowledge of `Data` (a private property).  The property changed notification is purely string-based, and the XAML binding looks for the property name from the change notification in its Path.  Since `Data` doesn't appear as a path component of `CCIRPrimaryID`, nothing happens.